# SQL- query - select best car num

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose you have the following tables:

```
TABLE Car
car_id
num

TABLE Car_description
dsc_id
car_id
model

TABLE Result
res_id
car_id
race_num
result
```

the task is to select max, average scores for races where we have more then 2 cars and Car.num, Car_description.model for best cars. i wrote the following query

```
SELECT 
race_num,
MAX(result),
AVG(result),
STDDEV(result)
FROM Result r, Car c, Car_description d
WHERE c.car_id = r.car_id AND d.car_id = c.car_id
HAVING COUNT(result) > 2
GROUP BY r.race_num
```

but i don't understand - how to select best car num and model for each race? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the car_id is a 1-1 mapping from car to car_description.

The following query uses row_number() to get the top car, based on the score.  This information may already be present in "result".

```
select r.race_num,
       MAX(score) as MaxScore,
       AVG(score) as AvgScore,
       MAX(case when seqnum = 1 then c.carnum end) as TopCarNum,
       MAX(case when seqnum = 1 then cd.model end) as TopCarModel
from (select r.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by race_num order by score desc) as seqnum
      from Result r
     ) r left outer join
     Car c
     on c.car_id = r.car_id left outer join
     Car_Description cd
     on c.car_id = d.car_id
group by r.race_num
having COUNT(*) > 2
```

The key to this is a group by, with conditionally choosing information about the top car.

Comment: Thanks. One question. The sorting of all race_nums here "ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by race_num order by score desc) as seqnum" will be uneffective, maybe there are some other means, to select only max element here, rather then sort all race_nums.

Comment: @AlexHoppus . . . What do you mean uneffective?  The purpose is to determine the car with the highest score, which is presumably the "best" (the original question does not define "best").  It is possible that result has this information, or that result = 1 for the best car.  In that case, the row_number() is not needed.

Comment: @AlexHoppus . . . It should not be more time consuming than the group by (so the query should be roughly equivalent to doing two group bys).  However, performance depends on many factors -- the server, how the data is partitioned, how the database is configured, and so on.  Do you want to post another question about performance?